# How to dynamically filter using a ListView

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I want to dynamically filter my results in the front-end using only my ListView class with a search input.

It should first display the entire list of users, but when something gets typed in the search input it should filter the results based upon that input.

What is the best/shortest way to do this using only my classBased View?

My current code:

Template:

```
<div class="card mt-3">
        <div class="card-body">
        <form action="" form="get">
            <input data-url="{% url 'klantbeheer' %}" class="zoekklanten" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Zoek op contactnaam...">
        </form>
        {% if object_list %}
                <div class="single-table">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table text-center">
                            <thead class="text-uppercase bg-dark">
                                <tr class="text-white">
                                    <th scope="col">Bedrijfsnaam</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Contactnaam</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Locatie</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Actie</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                {% for user in object_list %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ user.bedrijfsNaam }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ user.contactNaam }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ user.adres }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{% url 'klantupdaten' user.id  %}"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                                        <a href="#" data-url="{% url 'klantverwijderen' user.id %}" class="deletegebruiker" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#dynamic-modal"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% else %}
            <p>Geen gebruikers gevonden</p>
                <p>
                    <a href="{% url 'klantaanmaken' user.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Maak klant aan</a>
                </p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

View:

```
class ManageUserView(SuperUserRequired, ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'webapp/klant/beheerklant.html'


    #Query based upon contactName
    def get_queryset(self, query):
        

        #Contactnaam bevat QUERY EN superuser is vals.
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(contactNaam__icontains=query).exclude(is_superuser=True)
        
        return object_list

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = self.request.POST.get('query', '')
        print(query)
        self.get_queryset(query)
```

JQuery:

```
$('.zoekklanten').on('keyup', function(){
    var url = $(this).data('url')
    var query = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url:url,
        type:'POST',
        data:{
            'query':query
        },
        dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(xhr, settings){
                if(!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain){
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                }
            },
            success: function(result){
            },
            error: function(data){
            }

     })})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchInput").keyup(function() {
    var rows = $("#fbody").find("tr").hide();
    if (this.value.length) {
      var data = this.value.split(" ");
      $.each(data, function(i, v) {
        $("#fbody").find("tr td.contactNaam:contains(" + v + ")").parent().show();
      });
    } else rows.show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" /> 
Search: <input type="text" id="searchInput" style="margin:20px">
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">contactNaam</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="fbody">
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td class="contactNaam">Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td class="contactNaam">Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td class="contactNaam">Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. You think it's possible to query only on contactName via this way?

Comment: Updated my code above. Now the search recognizes only the column contactNaam. Just test it :-). If you like to play with the code here is the fiddle I made for you: https://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/4t0L6nem/2/